# iOS UITableViewFirst first Tap after scrolling to Top or Bottom ignored

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, scroll

When i scroll to the top or bottom in my UITableViews, the next Tap is not recognized. This is also recognizable by the not disappearing ScrollIndicator. The ScrollIndicator normaly disappears shortly after scrolling, but in this case it keeps visible until the first Tap.

My UIScrollViews are **not nested** in another UIScrollView or UITableView, which seams to be the reason for all the similar questions. I tried a lot of the possible solutions from those questions nontheless. But nothing helps

Im using:
iOS deployment target 8.0. Actual iPhone device has iOS 9.3.1.
Autolayout. Bouncing = false. Vertical scrolling.

**Things i tried:**

I enabled Bounce just for testing. But even with Bouncing enabled i can produce cases, where the ScrollView gets in the state, where the next tap is ignored. So i think bouncing is not the culprit

Playing around with the "Adjust Scroll View insets".
Playing around with the "ExtendEdges: ..." flags. 
Changed "Delays Content touches"

I tried overriding touchesCanceled and initiate my own first Tap programmatically as workaround by calling touchesBegan and touchesEnded, but it seams that this does not count as real Tap.

**So...**

What else can i try? How about a better way to programmatically Tap? (but keep in mind the AppReview)

**EDIT**

I was asked to post some relevant code.

Well i don't think i should post the Storyboard settings, also because the Storyboard settings are kinda explained above. Except, each UIViewController with the UITableViews has a UINavigationItem but without having an own UINavigationController. That may be important for the actual top position. And thats why i played with the "adjust scroll view insets" option. But im not so sure what else to take from that.

Here my viewDidLoad in the UITableViewController

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()

    super.viewDidLoad()

    // loading myDataList

    self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false
}
```

In my AppDelegate:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {            
    UITableView.appearance().bounces = false

    UIScrollView.appearance().indicatorStyle = UIScrollViewIndicatorStyle.White

    return true
}
```

Here are the tableView delegates, which i use in my UITableViewClasses:

```
override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return myDataList!.count
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cellIdentifier = "PlantTableViewCell"
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! PlantTableViewCell
    // ... setting up the cell
    return cell
}
```

The actions of the taps, which trigger normally are also just segues defined in storyboard. following code is normally called, except when the user scrolled to top or bottom:

```
override func shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier(identifier: String, sender: AnyObject?) -> Bool {
    // not called, when scrolled to top or bottom
    if identifier == ... 
}
```

I don't know, what else would be relevant.

Comment: You should post some of the relevant code.

Comment: can you please post some codes and tag me when you do?

Comment: Done. But sry, how do i tag?